# Count entry in SQL and Display Count side by side

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Im currently populating a datagridview from a sql database of 2 columns, there are entrys into the database of:

- Board | Defect

Data:

- Board 1 |   1
- Board 1 |   1
- Board 3 |   1
- Board 2 |   1
- Board 3 |   1

And im recieving a datagridview showing this info, but i want to add the items up so the datagridview will show.

- Board 1 | 2
- Board 2 | 1
- Board 3 | 2

Below is my code so far:

```
        Try
        connect()

        viewboards.AutoGenerateColumns = True

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT board, defect FROM [sqlccmdefects]"

        Dim viewboards_dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
        Dim viewboards_table As New DataTable()
        viewboards_table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        viewboards_dataAdapter.Fill(viewboards_table)
        Me.viewboards_bindingsource.DataSource = viewboards_table

        viewboards.DataSource = viewboards_bindingsource

        disconnect()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


    viewboards.Columns(0).Width = 142
    viewboards.Columns(1).Width = 100

    viewboards.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Board:"
    viewboards.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Defect:"


    viewboards.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

    viewboards.Rows(0).Selected = True
```

Any help would be brill, 
Many Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out following query

```
select board, count(defect) as defect from [sqlccmdefects] group by board
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you are having with this query? As it is correct query as per the data you have provided in question

Comment: I've tried the query, but the datagridview is now blank. Many Thanks,Pete

Comment: Should you not group by `board` rather than `defect`?